# SQL Server Report Service Stuck until I Stop/Start service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Frequently when we try to open up any SQL report, it just sits there. I then go to the database server and stop/start the SQL Reporting service. That fixes the reports for a week or 2, but it would then need reset again. I need to find what is the issue and how to resolve it. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Please could anybody have an idea about what's happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows Server 2012 and assuming you've installed to the default location, a good place to look for root cause is in the logs located at:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`

The next time this happens, open the most recent log file and search for any errors.

Comment: Hi pedram, Thanks for you answer. Do you have an idea about what kind of error I should search for?

Comment: I found this error: library!ReportServer_0-4!4888!04/28/2016-07:53:03:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '-------------/IIS02 Birth History - Traceability Data' cannot be found.;

Comment: Do you have enough disk space and memory? The fact that it works for two weeks without problems suggests a potential issue with system memory or virtual memory (on disk). If this is on a VM and you're allocating dynamic memory/space, that's another thing to look into.